# Calculate SQNR in frequency band

Tags: matlab, quantization

I want to calculate the SQNR of my signal.

```
fs = 44100;
fs_orig=44100;
nbits = 16;
[x1,fs,nbits]=wavread('Mysong.wav');

y=x1(:,1);
y=y*32768;
y=round(y);

%filter your data
[B1,A1] = butter(4,[90 715]/(fs_orig/2),'bandpass');
dataOut1 = filter(B1, A1, dataIn); % // filter command filters your music
```

First ‘remove’ the 4 least significant bits. So i devided the samples by 16, did round and then multiply again with 16.

```
d1 = dataOut1*16;

d2 = round(d1);
a = int32(d1);
b = int32(16);
C = idivide(a, b);

r = snr(dataOut1,fs,fs)
d = snr(double(C),fs,fs)
error_signal = minus(d,r)
%express in db
error_db = 20*log10(error_signal)
```

I calculated the error signal (difference between orginal and requantized signal). I come to the result of 6.4180e-05. Is this possible? When i converted it to db I had a result of -83.8519 db. Is this correct? What I did is it correct? The value looks so large.

Comment: some change you should do: in line 5) y16=int16(y*2^15); and to remove the 4 least bits you can do bitand, but you can do also: d1=floor(dataOut1/16)*16;

Comment: This brings me to a value of error_db = -71.3919, is this possible to have values like this?

Comment: If i use this [B1,A1] = butter(4,[3900 4525]/(fs_orig/2),'bandpass'); i become a error_db value of   16.7028 +27.2875i.